# Connect a VMCI stream socket

Tags: c, sockets, vmware

I'm trying to use VMCI sockets to make a stream-oriented connection between a virtual machine and its host. I successfully start the server, bind an address, put it in listening mode, and  call accept to wait for clients. However, whenever I call `connect(...)` from a client I get a `WSAECONNRESET` error.

My client code is:

```
int sockfd;    
WSADATA wsaData;
WORD wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

// initialize sockets for win32
if (WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData) != 0) {
    perror("Could not register with Winsock DLL.\n");
    exit(-1);
}

// get VMCI socket file descriptor
int afVMCI = VMCISock_GetAFValue();
if ((sockfd = socket(afVMCI, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("socket");
    exit(-1);
}

// initialize server address
struct sockaddr_vm their_addr = {0};
their_addr.svm_family = afVMCI;
their_addr.svm_cid = 2;
their_addr.svm_port = 1234;

// connect to server
if ((connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &their_addr, sizeof(their_addr))) == -1) {
    int e = WSAGetLastError();
    printf("Error: %d\n", e);
    exit(-1);
}

printf("Connected!\n");
```

The problem is not present whenever I use datagram sockets. (Of course, without calling listen, accept, and connect. In that case I simply use `sendto(...)` which works fine.)

Comment: I just want to clarify something: "whenever I call connect(...) on a client"... do you mean, "Whenever I call connect() from the client in order to connect to the server"? The wording right now makes it sound like the server is trying to connect to the client.

Comment: Per my reading of the WSAECONNRESET error description, this sounds like a problem on the server side. Does the server survive after a client connects?

Comment: Yes, I meant "connect from a client"; just fixed the question. I interpret that error message the same way, but the server seems to be just fine. At least I get no errors there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [VMware documentation](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vmci-sdk/VMCI-510-Relnotes.html), I just found:

> In Workstation 7.0, stream sockets were supported for Linux hosts, Linux guests, and Windows guests, but only datagram sockets were supported for Windows hosts.

Since my host PC runs Windows, this is not supported.